# React Redux Notification message

Tags: reactjs, notifications, message

I am new to React Redux, I have a notification component which show a message. I want to hide this message on click of this close icon. . here is my code. Please suggest.

```
export default class NotificationMessage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
    };
    _onClick() {
        console.log("close this button");

    };
    render() {
        var message;
        //let classerr = this.props.messageType ? 'notificationTheme.success' : 'notificationTheme.success';

        //let cssClasses = `${classerr}`;
        if(this.props.messageType=='success')
        {
            message = <div className={notificationTheme.success}>
                <span className={notificationTheme.message}>{this.props.content}</span>
                <i className={`${iconTheme['ic-remove']} ${notificationTheme.remove} ic-remove `} onClick={() => this._onClick()}/>

            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            message = <div className={notificationTheme.error}>
                <span className={notificationTheme.message}>{this.props.content}</span>
                <i className={`${iconTheme['ic-remove']} ${notificationTheme.remove} ic-remove `} onClick={() => this._onClick()}/>

            </div>
        }
        return (
            message
        )
    }
}

NotificationMessage.propTypes = {
    config: PropTypes.shape({
        content: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
};
```

Comment: are you using React with Redux or React on it's own?

Comment: react with redux and this is separate component called in every form. alling it based on a falag from a form -   {this.state.displaySNotification ?
                        <NotificationMessage content="Venue saved successfully" messageType="success"/> : 
                        ''} 
                    {this.state.displayENotification ?
                        <NotificationMessage content="Something went wrong" messageType="error"/> : 
                        ''}

Comment: You won't be able to hide the message from inside this component, unless you change the message to return an empty div, but i don't recommend that. Does this component render inside another? If so, I would use the state to control the rendering of the Notification component and pass in a function as a prop that updates the state.

Comment: Yes this component is called in another components through out my code, its called inside render method method of another component like below code -   {this.state.displaySNotification ?
                        <NotificationMessage content="Venue saved successfully" messageType="success"/> : 
                        ''} 
                    {this.state.displayENotification ?
                        <NotificationMessage content="Something went wrong" messageType="error"/> : 
                        ''}

Comment: How can I do this by returning message as empty div?

Comment: Just to add, even success and error both message has close icon,and I have to hide this message. Could not understand how to do with state as you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: See answer. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Pass through the onClick function from the outer component.

```
showMessage() {
   const { displayNotification } = this.state;
   this.setState({
      displayNotification: !displayNotification
   });
}
```

If you are basing the display of the notification on state, then just pass through the showMessage function as a prop to Notification to change the state on click of the close icon. Then when the close icon is clicked, it will change the displayNotification to false and hide the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the react state fDisplayNotification as true initially as such

```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {fDisplayNotification : true}
      this._onClick = this._onClick.bind(this);
    };
```

On button click event set the state to false

```
    _onClick() {
      this.setState({fDisplayNotification :false});
    }
```

This should trigger re-render of the component as state changed.

change your render method to return empty  if  this.state.fDisplayNotification is false.